# Maven dependency management issue

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I have a multi pom project, the parent pom imports an external module as such. This external module uses certain Saxon classes, I import it as such:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-framework</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

In the child pom, we import it as such:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-framework</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I was under the impression that if you imported it as such in the parent pom, all the transitive dependencies of the external module would be imported. When I'm building my project the saxon classes are missing and the only way I can get them to appear is to explicitly pull them down in my pom. Doesn't that defeat the point of transitive dependency resolution. am I going to have explicitly pull down all transitive dependencies in any project that imports that external module?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the scope of the dependency?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-framework</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

This should do the job.

Read on dependency scopes here:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

Comment: This is the default scope if none is provided, as above.

Comment: Correct, compile is the default scope.
But you chose 'provided' as your scope. Replace that with compile or remove it.